# Finding maximum of an integral

Tags: integration, optimization

My question relates to finding the maximum of an integral. I have two functions
$$ s_1 (t), s_2(t) $$
Now I have an integral that uses these two functions:

$$ \int_{0}^{T_b} s_2(t)^2 +s_1(t)^2 -2s_1(t)s_2(t)dt $$

The context for this quantity is that it needs to be maximized in order to minimize the probability of error of distinguishing received data along some communication channel.
Now in my textbook, they used the Cauchy-Schwarz theorem to maximize this.

I get the same answer (namely the integral is maximized when $s_1(t) = -s_2(t) $, however I get my answer when I take the derivative of the quantity inside the integral sign, and optimize it (set the derivative equal to 0 etc...)

The following information is also available:

$$ \int_0^{T_b} s_1(t)^2 = \int_0^{T_b} s_1(t)^2 = E $$

Where E is constant!

My question:

Is taking the derivative of the quantity inside the integral a valid method of maximizing, or do I have to use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to maximize this, and the fact that the answers match is just a coincidence ?

Many thanks!

Comment: What are the restrictions on $s_1$ and $s_2$? Because your Integral is unbounded. Take for example $s_1(t)\equiv n$ and $s_2(t)\equiv 0$. Then your integral converges to infinity for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I added some extra information I forgot to type out the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should show us your approach. To me it sounds suspicious that you only considered the integrand. I think that should give you some kind of point-wise answer. Also, I don't really see how to apply Cauchy-Schwarz here.

Comment: If you just take the derivative of the objective functional, you do not take into account the two constraints that you added. By the way, I guess that the second one involves $s_2$ rather than $s_1$. I would use a Lagrangian approach.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the Lagrangian in this case, because all local extrema for arbitrary $s_1$ and $s_2$ fulfill the property $\int_0^{T_b}s_1(t)^2\,dt = \int_0^{T_b}s_2(t)^2\,dt$.